# Python guessing game code keeps crashing after 1 guess. How would i fix this?

Tags: python

My code keeps crashing after I put in the 1st guess I make. I've looked at syntax and dont think that's a problem how do I make it so it goes past the 1st guess and executes it. When I put the guess in it just puts in all the prompts at once, and how do I call the function properly at the end? Any help would be appreciated.

```
Import time,os,random

def get_int(message):
  while True:
    user_input = input(message)
    try:
      user_input = int(user_input)
      print('Thats an integer!')
      break
    except:
      print('That does not work we need an integer!')
  return user_input

def game_loop():
  fin = False
  while not fin:
    a = get_int('give me a lower bound:')
    b = get_int('give me a upper bound:')
    if a < 0:
      print("that doesn't work")
    if a > b:
      a, b = b, a
    print(a,b)
    os.system('clear')
    print("The number you guess has to be between " + str(a) + "and " + str(b) + '.')
    num_guesses = 0
    target = random.randint(a,b)
    time_in = time.time()
    while True:
      print('You have guessed ' +  str(num_guesses)  + " times.")
      print()
      guess_input = get_int('guess a number')
      if guess_input == target:
        print("Congrats! You guessed the number!")
        time_uin = time.time()
        break
      elif guess_input < a or guess_input > b:
        print("guess was out of range... + 1 guess")
      elif guess_input < target:
        print("Your guess was too low")
      else:
        print("Your guess was to high")
      num_guesses = num_guesses + 1
      if num_guesses<3:
        print('Einstein?')
      else:
        print('you should be sorry')
      time_t = time_uin - time_in
      print('it took' + str(time_t) + 'seconds for you to guess a number')
      print()
      time_average = time_t / (num_guesses+1)
      print('It took an average of' + str(time_average)+"seconds per question")
      print()

    while True:
      play_again = input ('Type y to play again or n to stop')
      print()
      if play_again == 'n':
        fin = True
        print('Thank God')
        time.sleep(2)
        os.system('clear')
        break
      elif play_again == 'y':
        print('here we go again')
        time.sleep(2)
        os.system('clear')
        break
      else:
        print('WRONG CHOCICE')
      break 



game_loop()
```

Comment: Try the steps in https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Bro u > Dave Chappelle I fixed it btw

Answer (score 0):

If `guess_input` != `target` on the first iteration of the loop, `time_uin` is referenced before assignment. Hence the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time_uin' referenced before assignment
```

Solution is to run the following only if `guess_input` == `target`.

```
      if num_guesses<3:
        print('Einstein?')
      else:
        print('you should be sorry')
      time_t = time_uin - time_in
      print('it took' + str(time_t) + 'seconds for you to guess a number')
      print()
      time_average = time_t / (num_guesses+1)
      print('It took an average of' + str(time_average)+"seconds per question")
      print()
```

Please follow coppereyecat's link to learn how to debug a basic Python program.